# Why isn't this function working like I expect it to? Trying to determine if a string has two repeating consecutive letters, like the o's in book

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

So here's what I have so far...

```
function doubleCheck(str){
    for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++){
         var n = i + 1;
        if (str[i] === str[n]){
        return "True";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to Javascript. I googled around and I see there are better ways to solve this problem probably, but I can't figure out why this isn't working the way I think it should. If I pass a word without two consecutive letters like "train" this still returns true. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Because you’re always comparing `undefined` to `undefined` at the end by looping past the string’s length…

Comment: `i <= str.length` — classic [off-by-one error](/q/2939869/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you did `i <= str.length`.  Arrays in javascript start from 0.

In the case of 'train', it would go up to 5, which is undefined.
It would compare `undefined` (array[5]) with `undefined` (array[6]), which is true.